# Regex to capture everything inside ( ... ) but also handle cases where ( is used inside

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to capture using perl regex the data found inside this:

```
variable_myname(variable_data);
```

So I used:

```
variable_([A-Za-z_]+)(\s+)?\((.*?)\)
```

This allowed me to capture the myname of the variable (which is also prefixed by `variable_`) as well as the data inside the `(...)`.

However, this doesn't work if the user uses the (allowed) syntax of:

```
variable_oneexp("This is a value ( ... ) ");
```

Which because of `"`, the `(` and `)` should be ignored.

Same behavior should be handled if `'` is used:

```
variable_twoexp('This is a value ( ... ) ');
```

Finally, this behavior should also supported:

```
variable_threeexp('This is a value ' + ' another string ');
```

Though, I don't think the last example makes a difference for the regex.

Some pointers/assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negated class instead of the lazy `.*?`, then use some alternation to match anything between single/double quotes:

```
variable_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\(((?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|[^()])+)\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eP3pJ5)

I also removed the capture group around `\s+`, and turned it into `\s*` since I don't believe you need the spaces in a capture group. Revert it back if you need it.

Comment: Will give it a try, regex demo shows that it should work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use cases, so it's possible that a simple regex would suffice for you.  However, it's possible to more completely match this.  The following demonstrates the OP's regex, Jerry's regex, and my own against 6 different example functions.  The final 3 regex's are examples that Jarry's simpler solution will fail on.

I've included spacing in the regex using the `/x` modifier to make it easier to read:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$. - $_\n";

    # Original OP
    if (/variable_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\((.*?)\)/) {
        printf "OP: <%s>, <%s>\n", $1, $2;
    }

    # Jarry's Answer
    if (/variable_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\(((?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|[^()])+)\)/) {
        printf "A1: <%s>, <%s>\n", $1, $2;
    }

    # Covers all standard single and double quoted strings and parenthesis
    if (/variable_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\((
        (?:
            (?> [^'"()]+ )
            |
            ' (?: (?>[^'\\]+) | \\. )* '
            |
            " (?: (?>[^"\\]+) | \\. )* "
            |
            \( (?2) \)
        )*
    )\)/x) {
        printf "A2: <%s>, <%s>\n", $1, $2;
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
variable_oneexp("This is a value ( ... ) ");
variable_twoexp('This is a value ( ... ) ');
variable_threeexp('This is a value ' + ' another string ');
variable_fourexp('  \') <-- a paren');
variable_fiveexp(mysub('value'), 'value2');
variable_sixexp('This is a )(value ', variable_five("testing ()"), "st\")ring", (3-2)/1);
```

Outputs:

```
1 - variable_oneexp("This is a value ( ... ) ");
OP: <oneexp>, <"This is a value ( ... >
A1: <oneexp>, <"This is a value ( ... ) ">
A2: <oneexp>, <"This is a value ( ... ) ">

2 - variable_twoexp('This is a value ( ... ) ');
OP: <twoexp>, <'This is a value ( ... >
A1: <twoexp>, <'This is a value ( ... ) '>
A2: <twoexp>, <'This is a value ( ... ) '>

3 - variable_threeexp('This is a value ' + ' another string ');
OP: <threeexp>, <'This is a value ' + ' another string '>
A1: <threeexp>, <'This is a value ' + ' another string '>
A2: <threeexp>, <'This is a value ' + ' another string '>

4 - variable_fourexp('  \') <-- a paren');
OP: <fourexp>, <'  \'>
A1: <fourexp>, <'  \'>
A2: <fourexp>, <'  \') <-- a paren'>

5 - variable_fiveexp(mysub('value'), 'value2');
OP: <fiveexp>, <mysub('value'>
A2: <fiveexp>, <mysub('value'), 'value2'>

6 - variable_sixexp('This is a )(value ', variable_five("testing ()"), "st\")ring", (3-2)/1);
OP: <sixexp>, <'This is a >
A1: <sixexp>, <'This is a >
A2: <sixexp>, <'This is a )(value ', variable_five("testing ()"), "st\")ring", (3-2)/1>
```